# React and SCSS webapp only correctly formatted in Firefox, but not in Chrome or in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

#### General Problem

I'm developing a Webapp with React using TypeScript, SCSS and Bootstrap 4. I designed some cards with background images, overlays aka masks and a centered card heading as a component and reused this component in a Bootstrap row and column layout. The images are not equally sized. I use the `object-fit: cover` CSS property to resize them inside the parent container. Everything works fine in the Firefox browser on desktop and on my Android mobile device, but it does weird stuff in the Chrome and Safari browser on mobile and on desktop devices.

#### Code

Here is the code of the card component:

```
export default class CategoryCard extends Component<CardProps, CardState > {

    constructor(props: CardProps) {
        super(props);
        
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
    }

    onClick(event: any) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.props.clickHandler(this.props.heading)
    }

    getTextElement(str: string) {
        let strArr = str.split("&");
        if (strArr.length >= 2) {
            return <p>{strArr[0]} &<br />{strArr[1]}</p>
        }
        return <p>{str}</p>
    }

    getCenteredTextClass() {
        if (this.props.heading.length >= 11) {
            return style.centeredTextLong;
        }

        return style.centeredTextShort
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={[style.cardContainer].join(" ")}>
                <a href="" type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>
                    <img className={["w-100 h-100", style.categoryImage].join(" ")} src={this.props.image_src} />
                    <div className={[style.mask, "w-100 h-100"].join(" ")}>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <h4 className={[this.getCenteredTextClass(), style.centeredText, "text-white font-weight-bold"].join(" ")} style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                            {this.getTextElement(this.props.heading)}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </a>


            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

And the SCSS stylesheet:

```
.categoryImage {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 10px 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .mask {
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
  
  .centeredText {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 2,
  }
  
  .centeredTextShort {
    bottom: 80px !important;
    }
  
  .centeredTextLong {
    bottom: 90px !important;
  }
  
  .cardContainer {
    width: 205px;
    height: 145px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .mask {
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
  
  .centeredText {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .centeredTextShort {
    bottom: 140px;
    }
  
  .centeredTextLong {
    bottom: 150px;
  }
  
  .cardContainer {
    width: 350px;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```

#### Detailed Problem

So in Firefox it is all fine and looks like this:
[correct design in Firefox desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyEaQ.jpg)

But in Chrome it looks like this:
[two more or less correct cards and then 4 cards with wrong formatted images in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdSmT.jpg)

A slightly different problem occurs in Safari and in Firefox on IPhone devices and in the standard Android browser. But I guess it has the same solution.
It looks like some CSS settings for sizing the containers don't work, but only for some cards, which is weird, because all cards are using the same component.

Here is the code, where the Card component is used:

```
class CategoryCards extends Component<CategoryCardsProps> {

    constructor(props: CategoryCardsProps) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const cssClasses = "col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 d-flex justify-content-center"
        return (
            <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                {this.props.categories.map((category: CategoryData, i) => (
                    <div className={cssClasses}>
                        <CategoryCard key={category.name} heading={category.name} image_src={buildMediaUrl() + category.image} clickHandler={this.props.clickHandler} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

#### Question

Is there some setting, that i have to check, so that the formatting is the same in all browsers and on all devices (the Webapp is responsive)? Maybe some dpi or pixel settings or do i have to use some specific CSS properties for the different browsers in this case?

Comment: Please clear the cache of the browsers and check again if the issue still persists then do let me know here
use `Ctrl+F5` to hard refresh or clear cache on chrome and safari and on firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found an answer: The anchor-tag inside the div-tag for the CategoryCard component acts like a container and Chrome, not like Firefox, needs to know explicit the heigth and width of that anchor-"container". So the solution is to just add the bootstrap classes "w-100 h-100" to the anchor-tag and everything works as expected.